# Thread communication using C++14 and GLib (GDBus)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, glib

I'm designing a class which will create another object that runs in parallel. This parallel object will run a `GMainLoop` and listen for various events (DBus in this case). My issue is I'm unsure on how to communicate with a thread running in a `GMainLoop`. Am I forced to use the `GLib` methods of communication with that thread? I'd rather rely on the standard library as hopefully I will eventually be able to remove my dependency on `GLib` altogether. Here is a toy example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

#include <glib.h>

class ParallelTask
{
public:
ParallelTask() {
    std::cout << "I am alive!\n";

    // initialize _mainLoop (allocate, add signals, set priority, etc)
    // ...

    g_main_loop_run(_mainLoop);
};
~ParallelTask() {
    std::cout << "I am dead!\n";

    // Misc cleanup
    // ...

    g_main_loop_quit(_mainLoop);
}
private:
GMainLoop* _mainLoop;
};

class TaskManager
{
public:
TaskManager() = default;
~TaskManager() {join();}

void startTask() {

    _thread = std::thread([this](){_task = std::make_unique<ParallelTask>();}); 
}
void stopTask() {
    //??? Need to send message to Parallel task telling it to shut down
    join();
}

private:
void join() {
    if (_thread.joinable()) {
        _thread.join();
    }
};

std::thread _thread;
std::unique_ptr<ParallelTask> _task;
};

int main()
{
    TaskManager taskManager;
    taskManager.startTask();

    // Do other stuff

    taskManager.stopTask();
}
```

Additionally, I am running on a Linux based OS. I'd even prefer a `pthread` based solution over a`GLib` one. However, if no other solution is possible, I would gladly take `GLib` suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that for my needs I can use `g_main_context_iteration` instead of `g_main_loop_run`. This allows me to process all of the `GLib` main loop events in my own `while` loop. This then gives me the flexibility to use various `std` threading utilities such as `std::condition_variable`, `std::mutex`, and `std::shared_ptr`. Example of how to use `g_main_context_iteration`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

#include <glib.h>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void concurrentTask(std::atomic_bool& process)
{
    std::cout << "Beginning processing\n";

    GMainContext *context = g_main_context_default();

    // Register signals, etc...

    while (process == true)
    {
        g_main_context_iteration(context, true);
    }

    g_main_context_unref(context);
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic_bool process(true);

    std::thread task(concurrentTask, std::ref(process));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    process = false;
    task.join();
    std::cout << "Processing complete\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, though you should be aware of events getting stuck in the `GMainContext` queue due to being enqueued there just before you stop calling `g_main_context_iteration()`.